# How do I reduce cold start time using google cloud function instances?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

With firebase you can [write cloud functions in multiple files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#write_functions_in_multiple_files).
I have two functions, named "function1" and "function2", located in two separate files.

File: **function1.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');//This will be executed regardless of the function called
exports.function1 = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // ...
});
```

File: **function2.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');//This will be executed regardless of the function called
const admin = require('firebase-admin');//This will be executed regardless of the function called
exports.function2 = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // ...
});
```

Now I use **index.js** to export these files as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#write_functions_in_multiple_files).

File: **index.js**

```
const function1 = require('./function1');
const function2 = require('./function2');
exports.function1 = function1.function1;
exports.function2 = function2.function2;
```

When I execute **function1** I can access the "admin" variable from **function2**.
The obvious fix for this is to not declare the variable on the global scope.

Modified File: **function2.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');//This will be executed regardless of the function called
exports.function2 = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');//This will only be executed when function2 is called
    // ...
});
```

Now the "admin" variable is only initialized when I call **function2** and not **function1**.
Cloud Functions often [recycles](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations) the execution environment of a previous invocation.
If you declare a variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent invocations without having to be recomputed.
But now the "admin" variable will not be reused in subsequent invocations because it was not declared in the global scope.
So my question is how can store the "admin" variable on the global scope(so that it could be reused for multiple instances), but not have it initialized when **function1** is called?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is not possible.  By definition, two server instances cannot share memory.  They are completely isolated from each other.  Each function invocation runs isolated in its own instance, and two different functions can never reuse the same instance.  You will have to accept that the global memory space for function1 will never be seen by function2.

Watch this video to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCpKxpIMg6o

Answer (score 0):

After some research the answer is to [do lazy initialization of global variables](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_lazy_initialization_of_global_variables).
If you initialize variables in global scope, the initialization code will always be executed via a cold start invocation, increasing your function's latency.
If some objects are not used in all code paths, consider initializing them lazily on demand:

File: **function1.js**

```
exports.function1 = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    // ...
});
```

File: **function2.js**

```
exports.function2 = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    admin = admin || require('firebase-admin');
    // ...
});
```

Now I use **index.js** to export these files as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#do_lazy_initialization_of_global_variables).

File: **index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin;
const function1 = require('./function1');
const function2 = require('./function2');
exports.function1 = function1.function1;
exports.function2 = function2.function2;
```

This is particularly important if you define several functions in a single file or multiple files, and different functions use different variables.
Unless you use lazy initialization, you may waste resources on variables that are initialized but never used.